# How to transform a table with vacation start and end dates into a vacation dates list using Power Query?

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

We have the following table:

[image]

How to create a universal solution in Power Query that would transform vacation dates into a list (see below)

[image]

Comment: Reasons not to use images are [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/92546).

Comment: Did this answer solve your issue? If so please, accept it to mark the question as solved

Answer (score 1):

Try  this in powerquery

Add column, custom column with formula

```
= List.Transform({Number.From([vacation start])..Number.From([vacation end])}, each Date.From(_))
```

then use arrows atop the new column to expand to rows. Right click remove the extra columns

Full sample code:

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each List.Transform({Number.From([vacation start])..Number.From([vacation end])}, each Date.From(_))),
#"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom"),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded Custom",{"vacation start", "vacation end"})
in  #"Removed Columns"
```